# sql query with joins not returning certain data, can't seem to fix it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

i have 3 tables

**tbl_news_articles**

```
1   newsIDPrimary   int(4)
2   type    int(3)  
3   title   varchar(40) 
4   body    medium text
5   date    date
```

**tbl_images**

```
1   imageIDPrimary  int(4)
2   filename   varchar(40)
```

**tbl_news_images**

```
1   newsIDIndex int(4)
2   imageIDIndex    int(4)
```

so tbl_news_article hold the article data, tbl_images holds the image data, and tbl_new_images holds the id of the article and the id of the image.

each news article will usually have 1 image but could have multiple images, however sometimes there are no images for a specific news article.

Its when there are no images for an article the problem persists.

My query is

```
$sql = "SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.date, ni.newsID, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID 
            ORDER BY date DESC
```

which returns the following records

```
newsID -> 61
type -> 0
title -> title 1
body -> article body text
date -> 2016-10-01
newsID -> NULL
imageID -> NULL
imageID -> NULL
filename -> NULL

newsID -> 62
type -> 0
title -> title 2
body -> article body text
date -> 2016-10-01
newsID -> 62
imageID -> 2
imageID -> 2
filename -> group.jpg
```

on my website i display a snippet of each article with a link to the full article, the problem is when trying to click on the full article link on an article which has no images linked to it in the database the newsID row returns NULL instead of the actual newsID value.

my php code is

```
<?php
        //call the database to retreive the records
        $sql = "SELECT n.newsID, n.type, n.title, n.body, n.date, ni.newsID, ni.imageID, i.imageID, i.filename FROM tbl_news_articles AS n 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_news_images AS ni ON ni.newsID = n.newsID 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_images AS i ON i.imageID = ni.imageID 
        ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $i = 0;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $id = $row['newsID'];
                $link = "article.php?id=".$id;
                $type = $row['type'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $urltitle = strtolower($title);
                $urltitle = str_replace(" ","-",$urltitle);
                $body = $row['body'];
                #$bodytext = (strlen($body) > 130) ? substr($body,0,130).'...' : $bodytext;
                $pos= strpos($body, ' ', 140);
                $bodytext = substr($body,0,$pos); 
                $bodytext .= "... <a href='$link' title='$title'>read more</a>";
                $date = $row['date'];
                $formated_date = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date));
                $imgID = $row['imageID'];
                $filename = $row['filename'];
                if($filename != "")
                {
                    $imgLink = "images/news-articles/".$id."/".$filename;
                }
                else
                {
                    $imgLink = "images/news-item-placeholder.jpg";
                }
                $i++;
                if($i == 1)
                {
                    echo "<div class='news-spotlight'>";
                }
                elseif($i >=2 && $i <=3)
                {
                    if($i == "2")
                    {
                        $class = "first";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $class = "";
                    }
                    echo "<div class='news-highlight $class'>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<div class='news-item'>";
                }?>
                <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo $link?>"><img itemprop="image" src="<?php echo $imgLink?>" alt="<?php echo $title?>" title="<?php echo $title?>"></a>
                <div class='data'>

                <h3><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span itemprop="name"><?php echo $title?></span></a></h3>
                <div class="article-date"><?php echo $formated_date?></div>
                <span itemprop="startDate" content="<?php echo $date?>"></span>
                <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">          
                <span itemprop="address" content="England"></span>
                <span itemprop="name" content="MayoShinDo Association"></span>
                </div>
            <p itemprop="description"><?php echo $bodytext?></p>

            <?php if($i == 1)
            {?>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $link?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> link 4</a></li>
            </ul><?php
            }?>
            </div><?php
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "0 Results";   
        }?>
```

I'm sure the issue is with the joins but i've tried using inner join outer join and neither one returns the expected data.

i even tried using the following

```
$id = $row['n.newsID'];
```

to target the specific newsID field but that just broke things further
can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting both `n.newsID` and `ni.newsID`. When there's an image linked, these will be the same. But when there's no image linked, `n.newsID` contains the ID, while `ni.newsID` is `NULL`. If you select multiple columns with the same name, `$row['columnName']` will contain the last column in the `SELECT` list, so in this case it contains `ni.newsID`. Table name prefixes are not included in the column name in the associative array.

Either remove `ni.newsID` from the `SELECT` list, or give it an alias like `ni.newsID AS ni_newsID`. Then `$row['newsID']` will be `n.newsID`, while `$row['ni_newsID'] will be`ni.newsID`.

Comment: thank you very much!! a very clear and easy to understand answer. appreciate it